# Bug or numerical problem in nlme's corCAR1?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation

Consider the following example (yes, I haven't centered `age`, `corCAR1` is not necessarily needed here etc., so it is perhaps not the most meaningful model, I use it just to show the problem):

```
lme(distance ~ age + factor(Sex),random = ~ 1 | Subject,
   cor=corCAR1(form=~age|Subject),data = Orthodont)
```

Everything works perfectly.

Let's now multiply age, say, we measure it in months:

```
Orthodont$agemos <- Orthodont$age*12
lme(distance ~ agemos + factor(Sex),random = ~ 1 | Subject,
    cor=corCAR1(form=~agemos|Subject),data = Orthodont)
```

It shouldn't make any difference, but check the autocorrelation coefficient! It changed from $0.2418536$ to $0.2$... i.e. it stuck at its default value, as if it was not optimized at all! (One can verify that it is indeed the case, and $0.2$ was not a coincidence by calling `lme(distance ~ agemos + factor(Sex),random = ~ 1 | Subject, cor=corCAR1(0.1234,form=~agemos|Subject),data = Orthodont)` which will return a coefficient of $0.1234$ and so on.)

What's going on...?

Comment: You might do better on the R mixed models mailing list.

Comment: @mdewey Thank you very much for the suggestion, I'll give it a try!

Comment: In case anyone runs across this in the future, the OP @TamasFerenci posted to the R mixed models list, and this appears to be a problem in the nlme package.  It also happens with gls().  The main problem (as OP noticed!) is that it doesn't give a warning when it happens, so it could easily go unnoticed.  Ben Bolker posted some code in his reply that is useful for searching for apparently-ok starting values:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2018q1/026348.html